# In SAS, find mean value of all other observations in groups

Tags: sas, mean, proc

I am trying to find the **mean value of all other observation**s in the same group.

My data is like

```
Value        Name    Group   Mean_all_other
544          Pete      1        ....
997          Sara      1        ....
772          Tom       1        ....
725          Tris      2        ....
872          Lulu      2        ....
434          Mica      2        ....
728          Tina      2        ....
827          Bo        3        ....
322          Zu        3        ....
.....        ...     ...         ...
```

I know that `proc means` can give you the mean value within groups.
But here I want o create the **Mean value of all other in the same group**.

In this case, Pete under Mean_all_other will show 884.5, which equals to (997+772)/2.

And Sara= (544+772)/2=658;   Tris=(872+434+728)/3=678

Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `proc sql` solution using a subquery to average same `Group` for each row and conditioning out the current `Name`. Below query uses SAS's not equal operator `^=` and `mean()` function which in regular SQL would use the `<>` operator and `avg()` -both still compliant in SAS).

```
proc sql;
    create table NewTable as
      select * from
      (select main.Value, main.Name, main.Group,
            (select mean(sub.Value) 
             from CurrentTable sub
             where sub.Group = main.Group
             and sub.Name ^= main.Name) As Mean_all_other
       from CurrentTable as main)

quit;

* Value Name    Group   Mean_all_other
* 544   Pete    1       884.5
* 997   Sara    1       658
* 772   Tom     1       770.5
* 725   Tris    2       678
* 872   Lulu    2       629
* 434   Mica    2       775
* 728   Tina    2       677
* 827   Bo      3       322
* 322   Zu      3       827
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the mean for each whole group, the case-deleted mean for each observation is much easier to calculate. I'd suggest doing this via double DOW loop:

```
data have;
input Value  Name $   Group;
cards;
544          Pete      1
997          Sara      1
772          Tom       1
725          Tris      2
872          Lulu      2
434          Mica      2
728          Tina      2
827          Bo        3
322          Zu        3
;
run;

data want;
    do _N_ = 1 by 1 until(last.group);
        set have;
        by group;
        value_sum = sum(value_sum,value);
        value_count = sum(value_count,1);
    end;
    do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
        set have;
        mean_all_other = (value_sum - value)/(value_count - 1);
        output;
    end;
    drop value_:;
run;
```

Comment: Might be worth considering only incrementing `value_count` when `value` is not missing, as `proc means` would also exclude missing values from the mean.

Comment: It also doesn't work well for groups of size one, but it's a proof of concept at least.

Answer (score 1):

PROC SQL will happily remerge the summary statistics for you.  Note that this syntax probably will not work in other SQL implementations, but works fine in SAS. You can use the `DIVIDE` function to avoid dividing by zero for groups with only one member.

```
create table want as
  select *
       , divide(sum(value) - value, n(value) - 1) as mean_all_other
  from have
  group by group
;
```

For other SQL implementations you will need to re-merge the aggregate results yourself.

```
create table want as
  select a.*
       , divide(b.sum_value - a.value, b.n_value - 1) as mean_all_other
  from have a
     , (select group,sum(value) as sum_value,n(value) as n_value
        from have
        group by group
       ) b
  where a.group = b.group
;
```

If the value of `VALUE` could be missing then you need to add a `CASE` statement to handle those cases.

```
create table want as
  select *
       , case when (missing(value)) then mean(value)
              else divide(sum(value) - value, n(value) - 1)
         end as mean_all_other
  from have
  group by group
;
```

Comment: Both of these need to handle missing values better.

Comment: @RobertPenridge - Updated.